Validity of ticket when using alternative train from a different station
I have a ticket and seat reservation on an ICE leaving Berlin Hbf. But because reasons, it turns out it'd be a lot more convenient to board the train at Berlin-Spandau instead. So far that shouldn't be any issue; it's the next stop after Hbf. and only 10 minutes away. I just checked the DB website though, and it turns out exactly that ICE (same number, route and time of day) skipped Spandau yesterday.* To be clear: it was supposed to stop at Spandau, but didn't. Now I'm in doubt how safe it is to try to board the train in Spandau instead of Hbf.
*  There's "people on track" given as warning for the entire journey and likely explains a later delay, unclear whether that's the reason it didn't stop at Spandau. Not all that relevant though.
If a train gets cancelled or I otherwise can't reach it due to faults of Deutsche Bahn, I can simply use the next available one. Would this also be the case here? If I took the train at the scheduled time from Hbf. as I'm supposed to, I'd make it just fine. But if I decide to board it from a different station and it doesn't stop there, is that my fault, or DB's?
TL;DR: Am I running the risk of voiding my ticket if I want to board the train from a different station than originally purchased, and due to faults of Deutsche Bahn am unable to do so?

The anonymized ticket details are:
<City near Berlin> - Frankfurt(M)Flugh.
Zugbindung:
ICE XXX, hh:mm Uhr am dd.mm.yyyy
ICE YYYY, hh:mm Uhr am dd.mm.yyyy
Via: <1080>(L*EF*FD/BOK*SDL*H*GOE)*F

With the booked itinerary being City near Berlin — Berlin Hbf. — Frankfurt Hbf. — Frankfurt Flughafen.

Interesting, and possibly a case for lawyers (I think details matter). IMHO: you get a ticket from A to B on train C, and if DB cannot provide it, you can use other trains. But your station A2 was not in your travel contract. (and a person with A2 to B with C could uses other trains). -- I think if you depart to A2 (normal case), the ticket would be valid (but possibly not the seat reservations) -- I really think it is something lawyers can discuss for days and so I think nobody could really answer, but if DB put an explicit note

Are you sure it "skipped" the station contrary to the timetable? That might happen in India, but not in Germany. I suppose the information on the website might be inaccurate, but in reality the train did make a scheduled stop in Spandau.

@Johnnyjanko https://www.bahn.de/buchung/abfahrten-ankuenfte clearly said "Halt entfällt". Doesn't say anything about it anymore, I guess they don't keep historical live data for more than a day or so. Whether it actually did stop I can't tell, but according to online info it didn't. Seeing a bunch of random cancellations around Berlin recently, I'm not surprised by anything anymore.

This general issue is a total pita in Japan!  (Stations are never "missed", WTF Germany?, but you have to pay differently etc.)

@Johnnyjanko Seeing "people on track" I can imagine that the planned route was blocked for an unknown duration, so they decided to reroute the train along some track that does not lead through Spandau.

The main question is: What does the ticket say (not the itinerary printed on the same page!) Does it start in "BERLIN" or in "Berlin Hbf"? But I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of older questions that got answers.

@asdfex Added the details.

@asdfex And yes, there are older questions about Zugbindung and cancelled trains, but not in particular about missing a train at a station you didn’t book.

@Johnnyjanko When tracks need repair, the trains can be rerouted. Berlin-Spandau is often skipped when work needs to be done in the area of Stendal (further west). The train is re-routed through Potsdam (further south) and then take a parallel western route.


But if I decide to board it from a different station and it doesn't stop there, is that my fault, or DB's?

Depends on the ticket. With a Flex ticket you are good either way. With Sparpreis or Supersparpreis, this will be mostly your problem. This tickets have "Zugbindung", i.e. you are only allowed to use the trains that are printed on the ticket. Getting on at a later stop is generally allowed (https://drivest.de/4353/bahn-darf-man-an-einem-spaeteren-bahnhof-einsteigen-als-gebucht) but it's not explicitly part of the original contract and you may lose any seat reservation
"Zugbindung" is only voided if the ticket can't be used as booked because of excessive delay or cancellation. Since Spandau is not part of your ticket, chances are that "Zugbindung" still applies.
This being said, a single station being cancelled is quite rare and highly unusual so I think the risk here is quite small. Even if it goes sideways and you need to take a later train, you might find a sympathetic conductor (but that's hard to predict). This is very much an outlier case.

Yeah, thought as much, it'll likely depend on the conductor's goodwill. I agree that it's a very unlikely case, but it's hard to trust anything to do with trains at the moment in Berlin. ;)

RE Zugbindung is voided. Any source for that? My last known info (~5-10 years back) was that your ticket becomes invalid. You have to buy a new ticket and then request a refund afterwards. However, most conductors will let you board with your invalid ticket, but strictly speaking that is a gesture of goodwill ("Kulanz") not a passenger's right. I'll gladly stand corrected if this was updated in recent years.

@infinitezero: sure thing: https://www.bahn.de/faq/was-bedeutet-zugbindung . There is probably an English version of this but I'm currently too lazy to look for it since its not an easy term to translate and Google

@Hilmar oh great, didn't expect them to actually make a logical ruling.

In general I agree with your answer but I was pondering whether the specific case of Berlin Hbf and Berlin Spandau is different because for non-regional trains DB treats all stops within Berlin as the same. So the argument would be that OP has a ticket Berlin [any regular stop] to Hamburg, their train didn't stop where it was supposed to, hence DB is at fault, regardless of Spar or Flexticket.

It seems this station grouping I referred to is no longer universal but now ticket dependent (see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153799/city-ticket-included-for-german-ic-trains-validity) so if OPs ticket states Berlin Hbf they can't use the argument I made.

Re the risk being quite small: I've boarded trains at B Hbf that skipped the scheduled stop in Spandau at least twice. One was rerouted and went north instead of west, one  went through Spandau but did not stop since it was already overcrowded in Hbf. (I've gone with such trains from Berlin maybe 20 x in total in the last 6 a) I personally now go to Hbf rather than Spandau, although the latter is slightly easier to reach from where I usually come.

I intended to post this as a comment to Hilmar, but can't since this account is new:
As Hilmar states, a Sparpreis ticket wouldn't allow you to take another train just because a stop not specified in your booking is cancelled.
However, you have free choice of train in case your original train would arrive 20 minutes later than stated in the itinerary. In a situation where a train would have to completely skip a stop (like people on the tracks or having to reroute due to track repairs), it is very likely that this would also be the case, even if you were to enter the train at HBF.
(From personal experience, over 90% of my long distance trips in the recent past had delays of more than 30 minutes, so I wouldn't worry about Zugbindung anyway)
That said, your seat reservations will be void if you take a different train. Even if you take the original train and get to your seat with a certain delay due to entering later, your reservation might be void depending on how long you take.

In OP's case, the train was rerouted (probably just another route out of Berlin) after leaving the intended start of the trip (Berlin Hbf). Even if the planned stop in Spandau was left out, there is no reason to assume that the train didn't leave Hbf (the main station) in time.

@Tor It definitely was also delayed at the station after Spandau, but I don't remember exactly for how much. It might have hovered right around the 20 minute mark. I believe it left Hbf. more or less on time.
